# Creating a function to ask question from the user using scanf in C

Tags: c, function, user-input

I'm very new to C but am trying to make a function to ask the user a question using scanf, any suggestions of how I should go about this, this is currently what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[100];
int num, days;

int askQ(char *question, char *x, char *answer) {
    printf("%s", question);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(x,&answer);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    askQ("hello? | ", "%s\n", &name);
    printf("%s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will need to declare and allocate some memory for the `name` variable, e.g. `char name[100];`

Comment: Why are you passing `&answer` to `scanf`? Already, `answer` is the address you want to store the response in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things make this a bit tricky. Your requirement for an arbitrary format string makes it difficult to know how arguments are to be passed to `scanf()`. E.g. an int argument will require that you pass the address of the receiving variable to `scanf()`, whereas a string does not require the address because the "string" is already a pointer.

Similarly you should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure that the input was processed as expected - that's hard for an arbitrary format string.

Perhaps, if you really need arbitrary input parsing you can use [`vscanf()`](http://manpages.org/vscanf), but at your level I would not recommend that.

If you choose to keep it simple so that you simply have a prompt with a single string response then you might do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int askQ(char *question, char *format, char *answer) {
    printf("%s", question);
    int i = scanf(format, answer);
    return i == 1;
}

int main() {
    char name[100];    // accept up to 100 chars input
    if (askQ("hello? | ", "%s", name))
        printf("Response: %s\n", name);
    else
        printf("Failed to get valid response from user\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I eventually got it and have added to my own code with the improvements you made.